# What is the term for the unpleasant placement of the chair or sofa - in a way that you can be approached from behind?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, expressions, phrase-requests

What is the term for the unpleasant placement of the chair of sofa - in a way that you can be apporached from behind ?

I've heard several times that you should place all the sofas and tables that  you cannot be approached from behind.

Some people (psychologists?)  say that you have natural need to control your envirnonment, but you cannot if somebody can jump you from behind.

I cannot find papers on it, and I cannot though of appropriate expression for this phenomenon (or rather cue for interior designers)

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Haven't heard about it regarding sofas, but I have heard of the principle where people always sleep with their head *away* from the bedroom door, instead of head first. This rings true for all bedrooms I've seen, with the exception of those that simply couldn't actually fit a bed in such an arrangement (oddly shaped rooms, or a better reason not to do this, e.g. having a nice view from a window)

Comment: @Flater Are you able to find some papers on it? Maybe it have its own name?

Comment: It's been a long time since I heard it. I remember the principle, not the name (if it had any). Honestly, I seem to remember hearing this from Sheldon (The Big Bang Theory). So it's anecdotal at best sadly. I just hoped it would help you in finding actual studies on it, as it focuses on beds instead of sofas and tables.

Comment: It can be called feng shui, or it can be called the dead man's seat, like two pair, aces and nines, the dead man's hand in poker. Wild Bill Hickock was holding that hand when he was shot from the back while playing poker; normally he sat in a corner seat.

Comment: @JohnLawler, I've always heard [aces and eights](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_man%27s_hand).

Comment: I might describe such a sofa or table as being *exposed*, or being in an *exposed location*.

Comment: When it comes to "undesirable position of seats", I'd have much more use for *positive* terms - for example, it would be nice to be able to ***book a** [insert hypothetical adjective] **table at a restaurant***, and know that you've unambiguously but obliquely reserved any one of the tables that aren't right next to either the front door or the toilets.

Comment: @Hellion: My mistake, sorry.

Comment: @JohnLawler While feng shui is about positioning of furniture, I don't think it has to do with paranoia like this, it's more of a philosophical/spiritual thing.

Answer (score 2):

I found the term ***floating arrangement*** which is mentioned as an improper *feng shui* furniture arrangement.

> The main piece of furniture in a living room is usually the couch, which should rest against a solid wall. Currently, one of the popular western furniture arrangements is to place the seating group in the middle of the room without any wall support. This is called a floating arrangement and should be avoided.
>
> Chances are you feel safe and secure when sitting on the couch against the wall, while the one set in the middle of the room leaves you feeling vulnerable and uneasy, as though you need to constantly look behind you.
>
> <sub>http://feng-shui.lovetoknow.com/Feng_Shui_Living_Room</sub>